# How can i change the creation date of any nsf?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I need to change the creation date of an **nsf**.
How do i proceed with it???

i searched and found out that **database.Created** is an >> ***read-only*** value and cannot be changed.
[http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_CREATED_PROPERTY_DB.html](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATED_PROPERTY_DB.html)

Is there any way by which i can do so????

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why do you need to change the created date of the application (nsf)?

Comment: well, i just have copy nsf made recently whose creation date i want to replace with the original nsf.

Comment: First, build a time machine and go back in time to the date you want.... Why do you want the original date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the Database to a template by changing the file extension to .ntf, and then create a new database based on that template, that will change the created date

UPDATE:
You can also accomplish this using the "Database > New Copy" option (or Application > New Copy in version 8.x)

Comment: @Bebo, I tested this and it works for me.  I've updated my answer with another idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an operating system copy of the file, the Notes creation date should remain the same. Otherwise, you can't have a creation date earlier than today.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't think this is in general a good idea I didn't test this, but it might work :

- Shutdown the server.
- then make a OS copy of the NSF you want to manipulate to your PC.
- Change date/time of your local PC.
- Start Notes, make a copy.
- Copy this new NSF back to your server (OS copy).